# Check that a comma-separated string of codes contains the given code using regex

Tags: regex

I try to resolve my task using regex.

**Given:**

*string of comma-seprated codes*:

```
" 1004, 1001 , 11004, 1002, 1003, 1004 ,  1005,ABC100,10041,ABC102, 1004 "
```

- The string can contains numeric/string/mixed codes.
- Сodes are separated by commas.
- Between commas and codes there can be spaces.

*code to check*. For example:

```
"1004"
```

**Goal:**

Need to sure that the given code contains in the source string.

I prepared an ugly pattern but it works:

```
(?:,|^)[ ]*1004[ ]*(?=,)|(?<=,)[ ]*1004[ ]*(?:,|$)|^[ ]*1004[ ]*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/1

Is it possible to simplify it using the code one time in the pattern?
Thanks!

Comment: Idea: [`(?<![^ ,])1004(?![^ ,])`](https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/2)

Comment: What engine/program are you doing this in?

Comment: @bobblebubble, it seems it works for me,  thanks a lot!

Comment: If @bobblebubble's answer works for you, you should upvote it and mark it as accepted.

Comment: you're welcome @StanZeez

Comment: Given the current sample, `\b1004\b` will suffice.

Comment: right @WiktorStribiżew but not for such as `1003, 1004.3` i was thinking

Comment: @Graham, I need to use a custom sub-language in the working project that understand Java syntax. So, I need to resolve this problem using raw regex. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler idea can be to check by use of [negated classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) and negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if the searchterm is neither preceded nor followed by characters that are not `,` or [white-space](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

```
(?<![^\s,])1004(?![^\s,])
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/3)

Comment: [`(?<=[ ,])1004(?=[ ,])`](https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/4]) is a bit cleaner and more understandable, since there's no double negation.

Comment: @Graham Yes looks better understandable, but [won't match `1004` at start/end of string if there is no space](https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/5).

Comment: Ah, I see. Of course, [`(?<=^|[ ,])1004(?=[ ,]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/6) would work, but yours is less characters. Clever.

Comment: @Graham, [`(?<=^|[ ,])1004(?=[ ,]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/4IEi42/6) it is good idea to improvement, thanks!